# displaying country list with jquery

Tags: jquery

I got following results via ajax call:

```
{"results":["USA","Brazil"]}
```

I want to display country list as links like below example

[image]

Could you please check what is wrong with my jquery code:

```
var item = $('<div>');  

            $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {

                var country_name = $('<a href>');  

                country_name.html(res.results[]);  // I think this line is not correct            

                item.append(country_name);
            }); 

$("#country_list").html(item);
```

Comment: I think you also want '.text' not '.html', unless your web service is returning HTML tags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
country_name.html(res.results[]);
```

to

```
country_name.html(res);
```

Reason: `res` already contains the country name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'ajax.json',
beforeSend:function(){                  
},
success:function(country){
    var item = $('<div>');  
    $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {
        var country_name = $('<a href>');  
        country_name.html(res);  // you should use res here        
        item.append(country_name);
    }); 
    $("#country_list").html(item);          
},
error:function(){                   
}});
```

`res` variable already contains a country name since you have lopped trough an array.